# indexOfObject returns 0 first time instead of NSNotFound

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray

I have a table in a `UIPopoverController`, on `viewDidAppear` I check for the value of the cell label which is stored in standardUserDefaults. (So I can hilight the last selected option).

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *lastMenu = [prefs objectForKey:@"location"];

NSUInteger index = [__menuTitles indexOfObject:lastMenu];

NSLog(@"lastMenu is %@",lastMenu);
NSLog(@"lastMenu index is %i",index);
```

Produces this the first time the menu is activated

```
lastMenu is 
lastMenu index is 0
```

Subsequent clicks correctly report 2147483647 meaning `NSNotFound`

```
lastMenu is 
lastMenu index is 2147483647
```

Why does 0 get returned the first time???

Here's the array

```
__menuTitles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                @"North America", 
                @"Western Europe", 
                @"Asia Pacific", 
                @"Latin America", 
                @"Central & Eastern Europe", 
                @"Middle East", 
                @"Africa", 
                nil];
```

Comment: What's `__menuTitles`? Can it be `nil`?

Comment: this can be useful, if you will show us how the __menuTitles is initialized

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Likely means that `__menuTitles` is `nil` the first time around. Sending a message to `nil` will result in 0 being returned.

Comment: Most excellent answer, I sythasized with static NSArray *__menuTitles = nil; and built the list in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Problem sorted, thank you

Comment: Accept the answer to mark the question as solved if you please

Comment: Yes, but you have to wait 10 minutes before acceptance... patience is a virtue!